# Mocking NodeJS request and response with Nock

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, mocking, nock

I'm trying to get the grasp of the tool [Nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) in order to mock the request and response from my code doing the calls. I'm using npm request as a simple HTTP client to request the back-end REST API, Chai for the expectation library and Mocha to run my tests. Here is the code that I have for the tests:

```
 var nock = require('nock');
 var storyController = require('../modules/storyController');

 var getIssueResponse = {
   //JSON object that we expect from the API response.
 }

 it('It should get the issue JSON response', function(done) {
   nock('https://username.atlassian.net')
   .get('/rest/api/latest/issue/AL-6')
   .reply(200, getIssueResponse);

   storyController.getStoryStatus("AL-6", function(error, issueResponse) {
   var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(issueResponse);

   expect(jsonResponse).to.be.a('object');
   done();
 })
});
```

And here is the code to do the GET request:

```
 function getStoryStatus(storyTicketNumber, callback) {
   https.get('https://username.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/' + storyTicketNumber, function (res) {

   res.on('data', function(data) {
    callback(null, data.toString());
   });

   res.on('error', function(error) {
    callback(error);
   });
  })
 }
```

This single test is passing and I don't understand why. It seems like it is actually doing a real call and not using my fake nock request/response. If I comment the nock section or change:

```
 .reply(200, getIssueResponse) to .reply(404)
```

It doesn't break the test and nothing change, I'm not doing anything with my nock variable. Can someone please explain me with a clear example how to mock the request and response in my NodeJS http-client using Nock?

Comment: where is response end callback ?

Comment: @Dhirendra I think it's pretty clear in the posted code, the callback is my function that I'm passing called "callback" and the response is data.toString ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: I think your code is doing more than what it tells you.

Important note: when putting an http request in ["stream mode"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_two_modes) the `data` event could (and probably does) gets fired multiple times, each one for a "chunk" of data, over internet chunks could be variable between 1400 to 64000 bytes, so expect **multiple** callback invocations (that's a very special kind of bad)

As a simple suggestion, you can try using [request](https://github.com/request/request) or just concatenate the received data, then invoke the callback on the `end` event.

I have tried a very small snippet using the latter technique

```
var assert = require('assert');
var https = require('https');
var nock = require('nock');

function externalService(callback) {
  // directly from node documentation:
  // https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback
  https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {

    var data = '';
    res.on('data', (d) => {
      data += d;
    });

    res.on('end', () => callback(null, JSON.parse(data), res));
  // on request departure error (network is down?)
  // just invoke callback with first argument the error
  }).on('error', callback);
}


describe('Learning nock', () => {
  it('should intercept an https call', (done) => {
    var bogusMessage = 'this is not google, RLY!';

    var intercept = nock('https://encrypted.google.com').get('/')
      .reply(200, { message: bogusMessage });

    externalService((err, googleMessage, entireRes) => {
      if (err) return done(err);

      assert.ok(intercept.isDone());
      assert.ok(googleMessage);
      assert.strictEqual(googleMessage.message, bogusMessage);
      assert.strictEqual(entireRes.statusCode, 200);

      done();
    });

  })
})
```

And it works very fine, even with using `on('data')`

Edit:

[Reference on how to handle correctly a stream](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

I have expanded the example as a full-fledged mocha example

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see where you are using the 'end' event and where is your tests expectation? I'm not sure about how to mock HTTP requests with Nock, your code doesn't do much from what I already have. Maybe I'm wrong but if you can explain this?

Comment: Doing expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(404) will still let the tests passing

Comment: I have now made a full-fledged test, but of course it passes wildly.. I think you should start to isolate the problems. Try using a much simpler interface with request/request instead of vanilla node.js call, then check out if mocha is run correctly, and many other details that cannot be enlisted here

Comment: Thank you so much, I have a better understanding now! Last thing that I'm trying to figure it out: Is it possible to assert or expect the returned statusCode from the mocked response?